Dipole antennas and the $B$ field
A dipole antenna responds to the electric component of a EM wave.  Does the magnetic component of a EM wave have any effect on the performance of a receiving dipole antenna?

An electric dipole antenna is responsive to mostly  to the electric field but a magnetic dipole antenna ( a planar conducting wire loop) is responsive mostly to the magnetic field. If the "wire" of the electric dipole has a finite width, that is one made of a real metal, then it does have some sensitivity to the a magnetic  field.

That's what I thought.  Now, if half the energy is in the B field, and a receiver uses an electric dipole antenna, that sounds very inefficient.  Is there a way to use the whole signal, so to speak?  A professional antenna engineer would likely find this an elementary question.

That is an interesting observation. What cannot be done but you are alluding to is to achieve the same in the same volume because that would require a piece of metal to be responsive to both E and H equally and independently. In fact there have been attempts to do something similar but not exactly the same and for quite different reasons, see  this https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6768297, it is worth reading. But in practice, it is just easier to make what is called a diversity reception with two or more antennas, and this is widely used.

A loop whose circumference is a modest fraction of a wavelength responds to both electric and magnetic fields.

Electric and magnetic components of emitted electromagnetic field are related by an impedance, one obtained from another it is transverse electromagnetic wave (TEM) when the far field is considered. Thus one can only consider electric or magnetic field.
As for reception of the EM field, it is important to note the polarization of emitted wave and a polarization of wave that virtually emitted receiver. In fact there is a emitter-receiver polarization factor, similar to Malus law for polarizers.
